# python multithreading and file locking issues

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, locking

I have implemented multithreaded code in two ways, but in both ways I got an error. Could someone explain what causes the problem?

In version 1, I got an exception saying two arguments passed to writekey function instead of one. 
In version 2, one of the threads reads empty line, therefore exception is raised while processing the empty string.

I am using locks, shouldn't it prevent multiple threads accessing the function or file at the same time?

**Version 1:**

```
class SomeThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, somequeue, lockfile):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.myqueue = somequeue
        self.myfilelock = lockfile

    def writekey(key):
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join('.', outfile)):
            with open(outfile, 'r') as fc:
                readkey = int(fc.readline().rstrip())
            os.remove(os.path.join('.', outfile))

        with open(outfile, 'w') as fw:
            if readkey > key:
                fw.write(str(readkey))
            else:
                fw.write(str(key))

    def run(self):
        while(True):
            dict = self.myqueue.get()

            self.myfilelock.acquire()
            try:
                self.writekey(dict.get("key"))
            finally:
                self.myfilelock.release()

            self.myqueue.task_done()

populateQueue() # populate queue with objects    
filelock = threading.Lock()

for i in range(threadnum):
    thread = SomeThread(somequeue, filelock)
    thread.setDaemon(True)
    thread.start()

somequeue.join()
```

**Version 2:**

```
def writekey(key):
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join('.', outfile)):
        with open(outfile, 'r') as fc:
            # do something...

        os.remove(os.path.join('.', outfile))

    with open(outfile, 'w') as fw:
        # do something...

class SomeThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, somequeue, lockfile):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.myqueue = somequeue
        self.myfilelock = lockfile

    def run(self):
        while(True):
            dict = self.myqueue.get()

            self.myfilelock.acquire()
            try:
                writekey(dict.get("key"))
            finally:
                myfilelock.release()

            self.myqueue.task_done()

# Same as above ....
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the exceptions.

Comment: Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ....in run
    self.writekey(dict.get("key"))
  File ..., in writekey
    readkey = int(fc.readline().rstrip())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 1, `def writekey(key)` should be declared with "self" as the first parameter, i.e.

```
def writekey(self, key):
```

The problem in version 2 is less clear. I assume that an empty line is being read while reading `outfile`. This is normal and it indicates that the end-of-file has been reached. Normally you would just break out of your read loop. Usually it is preferable to read your file line-by-line in a `for` loop, e.g.

```
with open(outfile, 'r') as fc:
    for line in fc:
        # process the line
```

The for loop will terminate naturally upon reaching end-of-file.

Comment: Tried it that way. Got the same error with the version 2. I was reading from file and converting it to integer (int(fc.readline().rstrip())) in writekey() function. Exception is: Exception in thread Thread-4, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Exception is raised because line read is empty. However it should be written before in writekey() function.

Comment: Actually, outfile has only one line, storing the key. After the outfile is opened, the previous key is read and then file is deleted. The key passed as an argument is written afterwards to the newly created outfile.

Comment: `int('')` raises that exception. Don't process an empty line. Empty line means end-of-file - there is no data for you to process. You don't show that code, so we can't tell what is going on. Also, it's not necessary to delete the file - `open(outfile, 'w')` will truncate an existing file otherwise it will create it.

Comment: I have editted inside of the writekey() function. When I checked the file, there is nothing inside. There should always be a line with a key. How this can happen? I will try it without deleting the file.

Comment: OK, I have figured it out. Your first response, adding self to function argument list, fixed the first exception. The second one regarding int() was because of a logic error. I had an if clause inside the last else statement of writekey() function, because there is no else, nothing gets written to file :)

Comment: Thanks for hints though.